# XPath SyntaxError: invalid predicate

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xpath

I have a XML file like this:

```
$ cat sample.xml
<Requests>
        <Request>
                <ID>123</ID>
                <Items>
                        <Item>a item</Item>
                        <Item>b item</Item>
                        <Item>c item</Item>
                </Items>
        </Request>
        <Request>
                <ID>456</ID>
                <Items>
                        <Item>d item</Item>
                        <Item>e item</Item>
                </Items>
        </Request>
</Requests>
```

I simply want to extract the XML of `Request` elements which has certain value for their grandchild element `Item`. Here is code:

```
bash-4.2$ cat xsearch.py
import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


if __name__ == '__main__':
        tree = ET.parse(sys.argv[1])
        root = tree.getroot()
        for request in root.findall(".//Item[.='c item']/../.."):
        #for request in root.findall(".//Request[Items/Item = 'c item']"):
                print(request)
```

I got "invalid predicate"  error:

```
bash-4.2$ python3 xsearch.py sample.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 263, in iterfind
    selector = _cache[cache_key]
KeyError: (".//Item[.='c item']/../..", None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xsearch.py", line 8, in <module>
    for request in root.findall(".//Item[.='c item']/../.."):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 304, in findall
    return list(iterfind(elem, path, namespaces))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 277, in iterfind
    selector.append(ops[token[0]](next, token))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 233, in     prepare_predicate
    raise SyntaxError("invalid predicate")
SyntaxError: invalid predicate
```

Could any one point out where I got it wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, an XPath *invalid predicate* error means something is syntactically wrong with one of the XPath's predicates, the code between the `[` and `]`.

Specifically in your case, there are two issues:

1. The `SyntaxError("invalid predicate")` is because there's an extra `)` in the predicate:

   ```
    for request in root.findall(".//Item[.='c item')]/../.."):
                                                   ^
   ```

   Note also that you can hoist the predicate to avoid navigating down and then back up (`../..`):

   Instead of

   ```
    .//Item[.='c item']/../..
   ```

   consider

   ```
    .//Request[Items/Item = 'c item']
   ```

   to select the `Request` element with the targeted `Item`.
2. The XPath library you're using, [ElementTree, is not a full implementation of the XPath standard](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support).  You can waste a lot of time trying to identify what ElementTree does support (`".//Items[Item='c item']/.."` happens to work here) and does not support, but it'd be better to just use a more compliant library such as [lxml](https://lxml.de/).

Comment: Thanks for advice. But the same error perisists after I removed the extra ")".

Comment: Without the extra `)`, the predicate is fine.  Perhaps a new typo?   Copy (don't retype) your exact code into the question again as an update and perhaps we can spot the new issue.

Comment: I re-copied the code and the output. Could you please review. I also tried the second method, the error is exactly the same.

Comment: You can add to a question after it's been answered, but correcting code in the question to apply the solution suggested in the answer is really bad etiquette, it makes the thread impossible for a new reader to follow.